# Exposing UIkit in webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, getuikit

I'm quite a noob when it comes to technologies like webpack but I try to learn it.

I am using the default Angular 4 + ASP.NET core project in visual studio that has webpack configured in it. Now this project uses Bootstrap by default, but I would prefer to use UIkit. UIkit has a js library which uses the UIkit variable. More info can be found [here](https://getuikit.com/docs/webpack).

But the problem is that webpack seems to remove the global UIkit variable.

I have 2 webpack files. A [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/arnvanhoutte/Sankini/blob/master/Sankini/webpack.config.js) file and [webpack.config.vendor.js](https://github.com/arnvanhoutte/Sankini/blob/master/Sankini/webpack.config.vendor.js) file.

I tried exposing it using expose-loader and provideplugin, but it doesn't seem to work. I really don't understand why. I managed to expose jQuery by modifying my [boot.browser.ts](https://github.com/arnvanhoutte/Sankini/blob/master/Sankini/ClientApp/boot.browser.ts) and adding `import "expose-loader?$!jquery";import "expose-loader?jQuery!jquery";` but when I want to import UIkit it complains and says it `Module '"uikit"' has no default export.`.

I really would appreciate any help because I'm completely stuck with this and I don't know enough about typescript and webpack to advance

Answer (score 0):

Add this, i think it's a problem of typescript typing :

```
declare var UIkit:any;
export const uikit = UIkit;
```

or just install it

```
npm install --save @types/uikit
```

Comment: Where should I put this? Under `import UIkit from "uikit";`?

Comment: inside typings.d.ts not inside your component

Comment: or just execute this: "npm install --save @types/uikit" and you will be ok :)

Comment: I have installed the uikit types. Should I add these lines then in the index.d.ts of uikit types? Because if I do that it says there is a duplicate identifier uikit

Comment: don't add it if you installed types/uikit

Comment: I had installed types already, and it does seem to find my types. But it says that uikit is not a module (it is a namespace instead)

Comment: add this inside your index.d.ts : "declare module 'uikit ' { export = uikit ; }"

Comment: Hmm as you can see [here](https://github.com/arnvanhoutte/Sankini/blob/master/Sankini/Typings/uikit/index.d.ts) I have added this but still is not working